# Variadic template heterogeneous container

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, compile-time

I need to implement some variadic  template container class with heterogeneous elements, which allows  to iterate by these elements. My first idea is make class with std::tuple member with variadic arguments, but getting elements from tuple by array-like manner (via loops) is impossible:

```
struct A {void prnt(){std::cout<<"A\n";} };    
struct B {void prnt(){std::cout<<"B\n";} };    
struct C {void prnt(){std::cout<<"C\n";} };

template<typename...Arg>
struct Prc
{
    Prc() : NumElems(sizeof...(Arg)), mems(std::make_tuple(Arg()...)){}

    int NumElems;
    std::tuple<Arg...> mems;

    void process()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<NumElems; ++i)
         std::get<i>(mems).prnt();//It's forbidden: "i" must be a constant
    }
};

int main()
{
    Prc<A,B,C> obj;
    obj.process();
}
```

Any ideas?

P.S. I don't want use boost heterogenous containers, like **boost::variant** or **boost::any**

Comment: [Indices.](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "massive-like manner".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's it done using indicies:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <int... Is>
    struct index { };

    template <int N, int... Is>
    struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

    template <int... Is>
    struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : index<Is...> { };
}

template <typename...Args>
struct Prc
{
    std::tuple<Args...> mems;

    template <int... Is>
    void process(detail::index<Is...>)
    {
         auto l = { (std::get<Is>(mems).prnt(), 0) ... };
    }

    void process()
    {
        process(detail::gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>());
    }
};
```

Comment: Why I can't replace "namespace detail"? It's not compile in this case.

Comment: @gorill Sorry, I made a few mistakes in my original code. I updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: It's ok))) I have found them)))

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that iterates a tuple:

```
struct A { void print () { clog << "A" << endl; } };
struct B { void print () { clog << "B" << endl; } };
struct C { void print () { clog << "C" << endl; } };

template<unsigned N>
struct iter
{
    template<typename T>
    static void f (T &t)
    {
        iter<N-1>::f (t);
        get<N> (t).print ();
    }
};

template<>
struct iter<0>
{
    template<typename T>
    static void f (T &t)
    {
        get<0> (t).print ();
    }
};
```

And the calling code:

```
    tuple <A,B,C> t;
    iter<tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value-1>::f (t);
```

I think you could modify this to fit your needs.  NumElements in your code is known at compile time, so I think you would remove that member altogether.