# Template function error in tuple processing

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

In addition to topics: [Heterogeneous sequence generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934626/heterogeneous-sequence-generator) and [Variadic template heterogeneous container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913424/variadic-template-heterogeneous-container)
In the code below, I tried to handle sequence of objects in recurrent manner using templates - current object in tuple-sequence gets parameter from previous object:

```
namespace spec
{
    template <int... Idx>
    struct index { };

    template <int N, int... Idx>
    struct sequence : sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Idx...> { };

    template <int... Idx>
    struct sequence<1, Idx...> : index<Idx...> { };
}
template<int N> 
struct A
{
    A() : _N(N) {}
    template<int PrevN> void print_prevN(){std::cout<<PrevN<<std::endl;}
    int _N;
};

template<int N> 
struct B
{
    B(): _N(N){}
    template<int PrevN> void print_prevN(){std::cout<<PrevN<<std::endl;}
    int _N;
};

template<typename...Arg>
class HeterogenousContainer
{
public:

    void process(){process(spec::sequence<sizeof...(Arg)>());}

private:
    std::tuple<Arg...> elements;   
    template <int... Idx> void process(spec::index<Idx...>)//this function generates an error
    {auto aux = { (std::get<Idx>(elements).print_prevN<std::get<Idx-1>(elements)._N>(), 0) ... };}
};
int main()
{  
   HeterogenousContainer<A<3>, B<4>, B<2>> obj;
}
```

What's wrong?

```
error: expected primary-expression before «)» token
```

This error in the line:

```
{auto aux = { (std::get<Idx>(elements).print_prevN<std::get<Idx-1>(elements)._N>(), 0) ... };}
```

Comment: How would we know? There are no error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `print_prevN` is a function template (it's a [dependent name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)), so the succeeding `<` and `>` tokens are parsed as comparison operators.  Write:

```
{auto aux = { (std::get<Idx>(elements).template print_prevN<std::get<Idx-1>(elements)._N>(), 0) ... };}
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::get<Idx-1>(elements)._N` is not a constant expression, and thus not suitable as a template parameter in the expression `std::get<Idx>(elements).print_prevN<std::get<Idx-1>(elements)._N>()`.

Comment: If replace std::get<Idx-1>(elements)._N with constatnt, say, 3, will be the same error